# How to authenticate user using Microsoft Share To Teams Button?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

As described in this microsoft offcial doc, I have added share to teams button on my html page, but in pop-up that gets opened it gives error as

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams#:~:text=pop%2Dup%20experience%3A-,Embed%20a%20Share%20to%20Teams%20button,js%20script%20on%20your%20webpage.&text=Add%20a%20HTML%20element%20on,in%20the%20data%2Dhref%20attribute.&text=Alternatively%2C%20if%20you%20want%20a,icon%2Dpx%2Dsize%20attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams#:%7E:text=pop%2Dup%20experience%3A-,Embed%20a%20Share%20to%20Teams%20button,js%20script%20on%20your%20webpage.&text=Add%20a%20HTML%20element%20on,in%20the%20data%2Dhref%20attribute.&text=Alternatively%2C%20if%20you%20want%20a,icon%2Dpx%2Dsize%20attribute)

[image].

So how to authenticate the user, do we have to call another API for this or anything....

When I searched I found out about Graph API, but don't know is this what I need or how to use it.

I have created this simple html page.

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Teams</title>
    <script async defer src="https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Share to Teams</h1>
        <p>Please click on this icon below</p>
        <span
        class="teams-share-button"
        data-icon-px-size="64"
        data-href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview"
         data-preview="false"
        data-msg-text="Hello Avengers"
        data-assign-title="Demo Share"
        data-assign-instr="Demo Default Assignment Instructions"></span>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use of Freemium or guest accounts is not supported. If you use web browsers to stay signed into guest tenants or personal accounts then you will get this error.  Use work or school accounts instead.

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT I am using work account

Comment: Do I need to call other authentication api before it, if so can you guide me

Comment: There is no need to call other authentication. Remove cache in browser and check.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @Mamatha-MSTF Actually what is happening is I am opening this in chrome browser, in which I have login with microsoft work account, but this share to teams is getting opened in new chrome window, may be this is the reason, that its giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I opened share to teams button html file in incognito window I am able to repro your issue.

I have raised a bug for this issue and concerned team is working on it.

Alternatively you can use below code and Please go [through](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2019/08/adding-a-share-to-teams-button-on-your-website-plus-variations/) this.

```
<div class="teams-share-button" data-href="https://learn.microsoft.com">
<a target="ms-teams-share-popup" onclick="window.open('https://teams.microsoft.com/share?href=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com&amp;referrer=learn.microsoft.com', 'ms-teams-share-popup', 'width=700,height=600'); return false" href="https://teams.microsoft.com/share?href=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com&amp;referrer=learn.microsoft.com">
<img alt="Share to Microsoft Teams" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0i...Zz4=" width="32" height="32">
</a>
</div>
```